# Animate CCSprite's color

Tags: colors, cocos2d-iphone, jquery-animate

I have a CCSprite that uses the setColor method to override its color. E.g.

```
[mySprite setColor:ccBLUE];
```

which works great!

Problem is I want to animate this property but I can't find any resources that instruct how to do this (other than doing it manually!!!)

What I'd like to do is something like this:

```
[mySprite runAction:[ccColorAnimate toValue:ccc3FromUInt(0x00FF00) withDuration:0.5f]];
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a subclass of CCActionInterval to make it. Look throw the code of any it's subclass to understand, what do you need to implement.

Comment: I see, if this functionality isn't built into cocos2d already I guess I should make it! Unless someone else already has